# Can not access react props data when I try to access it. Getting TypeError error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The Redux action creator get fired and makes fetch request to my server then returns data back to React `Lead` component. But I can access the the data to update the UI. When I console log the data it shows that is an array object, but when i try accessing the data in the component using `map()` it returns the leads props as `undefined`. Could it be because of the type checking I set for the incoming state?

Also, when I comment out the Type checking object set and try to access tha array object data I get a  `TypeError` error: `TypeError: props.leads is undefined`, but I can console log it and it shows.

Why do I get an `undefined` data when I try to access it, but logs to the browser interpreter, when I only console log it?.

## SOUCE CODE BELOW

#### Redux action:

```
import GET_LEADS from './types';

// GET LEADS
export const getLeads = () => (dispatch) => {
    fetch('/api/leads/')
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status != 200) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }

        return response.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_LEADS,
            payload: res
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

### Redux reducers

#### Leads reducer:

```
import { GET_LEADS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    leads: []
};


export default function leads(state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.types) {
        case GET_LEADS:
            return {
                ...state,
                leads: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

#### Combined reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import leads from './leads';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    leads: leads
});

export default rootReducer;
```

#### React Leads component (container, because it connect to redux):

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { getLeads } from '../../actions/leads';

export function Lead(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getLeads();
    },[]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="table-responsive-lg">
                <table className="table table-hover table-sm shadow-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope='col'>ID</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Title</th>
                            <th scope='col'>F-Name</th>
                            <th scope='col'>M-Name</th>
                            <th scope='col'>L-Name</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Phone</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Company</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Website</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Address</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Addr_1</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Addr_2</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Addr City</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Addr State</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Addr Country</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Sale Rep</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Status</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Priority</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {props.leads[0].map(lead => (   // <---- TypeError: props.leads is undefined
                            <tr key={lead.id}>
                                <td>{lead.id}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                        {console.log(props.leads)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

Lead.propTypes = {
    leads: PropTypes.array.isRequired, // <--- type checking for array object
    getLeads: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({getLeads}, dispatch);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ leads: state.leads.leads });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Lead);
```

Comment: I would add some conditionals, because the array is empty at first, you're trying to map an object, you need to remove the 0 from the map like this props.leads.map, also have some conditions to display something else or nothing when the array is empty, because the map will try to iterate an empty array.

Comment: @jean Aguilar I did this, but a I got a whole new error of  `TypeError: t is undefined`.  I didn't update the repo with the code, but could show how you would implement it? [here](https://github.com/Romeo-Peter/storeleads/blob/redux/frontend/src/containers/leads/leads.js) is the link. You can fork the project and create a branch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the `tbody` tag

```
{props.leads && props.leads[0].map(  
                            <tr key={lead.id}>
                                <td>{lead.id}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
```

Comment: I dont't think this is right. There is really know need to get the index of the array since it's empty at first. I implemented a conditional to check if the array if filled before doing access it but got an error of `TypeError: t is undefined`. do check the response comment to @JeanAguilar for more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo in switch statement it should be `switch(action.type)` without 's, that's why when action is triggered it can't find correspond action type in reducer and data is not loaded to redux store

Comment: The switch statement seems fine and data get loaded in the redux store

Comment: Then try what Jean Aguilar commented, there is no need to write props.leads[0], because initial state is empty array so it fine to write props.leads.map()